# For how many consecutive numbers Collatz conjecture was checked?

Tags: computational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

[I heard here](http://thatsmaths.com/2013/07/11/the-ups-and-downs-of-hailstone-numbers/) that Collatz conjecture was checked at least for every first $5 \cdot 10^{18}$ natural numbers, but I cannot find any source or actual information about this. Can anyone help to find out up to which number (or factor of `10`) we can now say that Collatz Conjecture is definitely true?

Comment: I t would be better to include the term "consecutive numbers" in the title; I think this is more explanative because it is simple to refer to classes of infinitely many numbers for which the Collatz conjecture is true: if you have an odd number $n_0$ for which the conjecture is true, then iteratively for all $n_{k+1}=4n_k+1$ the conjecture is also true. Written as bitstring we can begin with $n_0=1$, then $n_1=101,n_2=10101,n_3=1010101,...$ are also numbers for which the conjecture is true -but the set is sparse. Thus the benefit of Oliveira's tables is, that they cover contiguous intervals.

Comment: The same question in 2019: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314430/how-far-has-collatz-conjecture-been-computationally-verified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following published paper gives $20\times 2^{58}\approx 5.7646\times 10^{18}$:

Tomás Oliveira e Silva, "Empirical Verification of the 3x+1 and Related Conjectures." In "The Ultimate Challenge: The 3x+1 Problem," (edited by Jeffrey C. Lagarias), pp. 189-207, American Mathematical Society, 2010.

The author's [website](http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/bib/3.5.html) suggests ongoing work, but the sublink is down.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is a few orders of magnitude too low. According to [this discussion board](http://boinc.thesonntags.com/collatz/forum_thread.php?id=344), the number is at least $2 \cdot 10^{21}$.

Answer (score 2):

The official number [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CollatzProblem.html) gives is $5.48×10^{18}$.