# How far has Collatz conjecture been computationally verified?

Tags: reference-request, computational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

[This page from 2017 by Eric Roosendaal](http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/) says that the yoyo@home project checked for convergence all numbers up to approx. 2<sup>66</sup>. Is it still a valid record? I am aware of the ongoing BOINC project, but I cannot find how far they are.

The same question from 2014: [For how many consecutive numbers Collatz conjecture was checked?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808829/for-how-many-consecutive-numbers-collatz-conjecture-was-checked)

Comment: This lists the record as of last month:  http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/progress.html

Comment: https://boinc.thesonntags.com/collatz/highest_steps.php this was three clicks away from the BOINC homepage

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If I understand this page correctly, then the project verified all numbers up to $509\,040 \times 20 \times 10^{12}$, which corresponds to approx. $2^{63}$. This is less than $2^{66}$. How does this project relate to the original page by Eric Roosendaal claiming that checked all numbers below $2^{66}$?

Comment: @Bananach This page just lists the numbers having the highest number of steps so far. It says nothing about how much the problem was verified. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: [This (in German)](https://www.uni-flensburg.de/mathematik/wer-wir-sind/mitarbeiterinnen-und-mitarbeiter/dr-christian-hercher/forschung/zur-collatz-vermutung-und-nicht-trivialen-collatz-zyklen/) seems to be an article explaining the Collatz sub-project. Would anyone be able to translate it for me?

Comment: Just open in Chrome browser and click **translate**... it gives a great translation.

Comment: I believe this answer needs to be updated

Comment: @klutt Updated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since nobody provided an answer to my question, I will answer myself.

- As of August 2019, I am aware of ongoing BOINC project [[1](https://pcbarina.fit.vutbr.cz/)](https://boinc.thesonntags.com/collatz/).
  By personal correspondence with Eric Roosendaal I found that this ongoing BOINC project is meant to disprove the Collatz conjecture by trying to find a counter-example.
  The project started off in the middle of nowhere, at $2^{71}$ apparently, without specifying any arguments
  why this was chosen or why this would be a sensible point to use.  It looks like they have reached roughly $2^{72.3}$ or so.
  No info is given as to whether all numbers up to that limit have indeed be checked.
- As of August 2019, I am also aware of another ongoing project [[2]](http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/) by Eric Roosendaal. All numbers up to $2^{60} \approx 10^{18}$ have been checked for convergence.
- In 2017, the yoyo@home project [[3]](http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/) [[4]](https://www.uni-flensburg.de/mathematik/wer-wir-sind/mitarbeiterinnen-und-mitarbeiter/dr-christian-hercher/forschung/zur-collatz-vermutung-und-nicht-trivialen-collatz-zyklen/) checked for convergence all numbers up to $10^{20} \approx 2^{66.4}$.
- The paper by Tomás Oliveira e Silva [[5]](https://books.google.cz/books?id=hekJ7JDMEVkC&pg=PA189) from 2010 claims that the author verified the conjecture up to $2^{62.3} \approx 5.76 \times 10^{18}$. Source: Tomás Oliveira e Silva, "Empirical Verification of the 3x+1 and Related Conjectures." In "The Ultimate Challenge: The 3x+1 Problem," (edited by Jeffrey C. Lagarias), pp. 189-207, American Mathematical Society, 2010.
- The page [[6]](http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/3x_plus_1.html) by Tomás Oliveira e Silva states that, in 2009, they verified the conjecture up to $2^{62.3}$.
- Earlier, in 2008, Tomás Oliveira e Silva [[6]](http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/3x_plus_1.html) tested all numbers below $19\times 2^{58}$.
- Much earlier, in 1992, Leavens and Vermeulen verified the convergence for all numbers below $5.6 \times 10^{13} \approx 2^{45.67}$. Source: Leavens, G. T. and Vermeulen, M. "3x+1 Search Programs." Comput. Math. Appl. 24, 79-99, 1992.
- By the way, the paper [[7]](https://www.mdpi.com/2306-5729/4/2/89) from 2019 confirms to me that the largest integer being (consecutively) verified is about $2^{60}$, referring to above sources.

---

When I put it all together, I get the upper bound $2^{66.4}$.

**UPDATE:**

From September 2019 to May 2020, my project [[8]](https://rdcu.be/b5nn1) managed to verify the Collatz conjecture for all numbers below $2^{68}$. So the current upper bound is $2^{68}$.

**UPDATE 2:**

On December 10, 2021, [my ongoing project](https://pcbarina.fit.vutbr.cz/) managed to verify the convergence of all numbers below $2^{69}$. As of October 19, 2022, the current bound is $645 × 2^{60}$ (≈ $2^{69.33}$).

**UPDATE 3:**

As of July 9, 2023, [my project](https://pcbarina.fit.vutbr.cz/) was finally able to verify the validity of the Collatz conjecture for all numbers less than $2^{70}$.

**UPDATE 4:**

On November 3, 2023, [my project](https://pcbarina.fit.vutbr.cz/) verified the validity of the Collatz conjecture for all numbers less than $1.5 \times 2^{70}$ ($= 1536 \times 2^{60}$).
This is the moment when the length of a non-trivial cycle raises to 355 504 839 929.
See the article from Hercher, C. (2023). ["There are no Collatz m-cycles with m <= 91"](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL26/Hercher/hercher5.pdf) (PDF). Journal of Integer Sequences. 26 (3): Article 23.3.5.

Comment: Applause! Please do also a notification on mathoverflow.net

Comment: @GottfriedHelms The notification is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364752/verification-of-the-collatz-problem). However, it does not seem to be welcome there.

Comment: Verry sorry, @DaBler. Didn't consider my proposal well. Hope, the closing of your msg does not hurt you... Perhaps it would have been wiser to make a question "what is the current status of the numerical verification" and then give a self answer. But really - I didn't think about this enough.

Comment: @DaBler That's a very clever way to aggregate steps, congrats!
I might have an idea to hopefully add 1 to the exponent with only a slight change in the formula and without increasing the computations and I'm curious for an opinion or a test.
If we take the sequences modulo 6 it's easy to see that every number reaches 4, therefore if we have N=6n+4 --> N'=6n'+4 and we focus on the change in the coefficient n-->n' we get a new formula that is similar enough to the original one. To verify the original up to N it should be enough to check the new up to N/2.
Not enough characters for details...

Comment: @Carsaxy Can you please explain more in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139267/how-far-has-collatz-conjecture-been-computationally-verified)?

Comment: @DaBler sure, I just did.

Comment: *(Just for the record, from another comment of mine)* "Recently, the user @DaBler has announced $\chi_{2022}=645 \cdot 2^{60}$. I've not seen a confirmation of this, But if this is true, then a cycle of length $N=1'546'343'459'710'263'321'923$ odd steps is disproved (with my simple method) and after a series of heuristics, it seems, this is also the longest disprovable cycle using the new $\chi_{2022}$ (this assumes that the structure is a "k-cycle" with $k>90$, because "k-cycles" with smaller $k$ are already disproved for any length)" (see comment at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3127885/)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms As of January 6, 2023, my project was able to verify the validity of the Collatz conjecture for all numbers less than $660 × 2^{60}$ (≈ $2^{69.37}$). See [here](https://pcbarina.fit.vutbr.cz/) for current status.

Comment: I've to correct an error (source unclear yet) to my prev. comment. The given $N$ is wrong, my simple method doesn't disprove "a cycle of that $N$"  ; a recalculation plus more heuristics give even an improvement to $N=1'546'344'187'744'718'534'528$ (using $\chi_{2022}=645 \cdot 2^{60}$

Comment: It seems, that for $\chi_{2301}=660 \cdot 2^{60}$ the longest disprovable general cycle (not small-m "m-cycle") is $N=1'582'282'699'088'924'797'319$ (odd steps). However this is only heuristic so far, I see this now as challenge, to be improved...

Comment: Using $\chi_{2301} $ I've got one larger $N$: $N=1'582'305'694'802'731'032'874$ cannot be the length of a cycle. After that about $41 e9$ candidates remain, which would need 22 hrs to test...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Is your simple method published somewhere? Where can I read how to extend it for new $\chi$?

Comment: Dabler - I just remember I had recently posted an Q&A on this here : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3138566/1714 The explanation in the answer there is much more extended than my comments here - the required shortness in comments spoils the precision of text unfortunately and is prone to needless small errors in notation :-(

Comment: I'm currently trying to find the largest disprovable cycle-length on base of your $\chi = 645 \times 2^{60}$ Manually I found (15'th optimaziation) $N_{15}=1\,546\,344\,201\,699\,447\,217\,164$ but in view of an upper bound for such an $N$ by $N_\chi = 1\,546\,344\,201\,779\,196\,168\,856$ it is hopeless to perform the tests on all sequential $N$ in between. (...)

Comment: (...)  However, I'm just trying some new idea for an automatable method based on convgts of cont.frac. $\log_2(3)$, perhaps I can say more tomorrow. If I get this to work I'll put the maximal $N$-values for your $\chi_{22}=645 \times 2^{60}$ and the new $\chi_{23}=2^{70}$ here.

Comment: By heuristics (mainly based on generalized convgts of cont frac) I conjecture now for $\chi_{2307}=2^{70}$ the largest length $N$ for which a cycle can be disproved with the simple method is now $N_{2307(1)}=2\,454\,971\,259\,794\,877\,266\,896$

Comment: (Sorry @DaBler - still don't have a fully functional automatic determination; still need manually tuning of finding optimal guessings. The final open space for $N$ is still $6 \times 10^10$ and likely cannot be done sequentially in reasonable computing time.)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Look, I've updated my answer.